# Ajax links that is processed in separate js file

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

i using multiple links in my web app and i want to process ajax funcionality in javascript file to simplify things. It is this approach vulnerable to XSS Attack? Thanks

```
<a class="ajaxSortTrigger float-left" data-tf-ajax="true" data-tf-method="GET" data-tf-target="#bookList"
               href="/wtf/Book?booktype=@Request.Params["bookType"]&sortOrder=Price_desc">max</a>
```

javascript

```
$(".ajaxSortTrigger[data-tf-ajax='true']").click(function (link) {
        link.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        var options = 
            {
                url: $this.attr("href"),
                type: $this.attr("data-tf-method"),
                cache: false,
                dataType: "html",
            }

        $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
            var $target = $($this.attr("data-tf-target"));
            $target.replaceWith(data);
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Cross-site scripting (XSS) is about injecting client-side script to web page viewed by other users. Your code simply change behaviour of ordinary links to make a ajax request instead of sync request. I don't see here any possibility of XSS attacks.